# Find next daylight savings dates by time-zone (BST/GMT, CET/CEST, etc.)

Tags: go, timezone, dst

According to the rules of British Summer Time (BST) / daylight saving time (DST) (https://www.gov.uk/when-do-the-clocks-change) the clocks:

- go forward 1 hour at 1am on the last Sunday in March (beginning of BST),
- go back 1 hour at 2am on the last Sunday in October (beginning of Greenwich Mean Time GMT = Universal Time Coordinated UTC).

In 2019 this civil local time change happens on March 31st and October 27th, but the days slightly change every year.

A similar DST rule applies to Central European Time CET (Winter) > CEST (Summer) checking the last Sunday of March/October (https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/denmark/copenhagen). The combination of these BST/GMT and CET/CEST rules affect e.g. all the countries around the North Sea. Regardless BST/GMT, or CET/CEST, the UTC timestamp underneath should be the same.

I've written the following code based on `time.UTC` providing the dates for BST/GMT, but I am wondering if there is a simpler / more general way to use an arbitrary `time.Location` that could be applicable to CET/CEST and (ideally) any DST rule.

- Checking the docs (here https://golang.org/pkg/time/#FixedZone) it seems that `time.FixedZone` should deal with invariant time-zones, but what's the `offset` in there? How can I make the following functions invariant from the time-zone?
- Is there a way to avoid that `for` loop on the Sunday(s) of the month?
- Is there a way to avoid an hard-coded `map` based on BST/GMT or CET/CEST and the month, to find out the next clock change?

The code:

```golang
func beginOfMonth(year, month int, loc *time.Location) time.Time {
    return time.Date(year, time.Month(month), 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, loc)
}

// https://www.gov.uk/when-do-the-clocks-change
func lastUTCSunday(year, month int) time.Time {
    beginOfMonth := beginOfMonth(year, month, time.UTC)
    // we can find max 5 sundays in a month
    sundays := make([]time.Time, 5)
    for d := 1; d <= 31; d++ {
        currDay := beginOfMonth.Add(time.Duration(24*d) * time.Hour)
        if currDay.Weekday().String() == "Sunday" {
            sundays = append(sundays, currDay)
        }
        if currDay.Month() != beginOfMonth.Month() {
            break
        }
    }
    // check if last date is same month
    if sundays[len(sundays)-1].Month() == beginOfMonth.Month() {
        // the 5th sunday
        return sundays[len(sundays)-1]
    }
    // if not like before, then we only have 4 Sundays
    return sundays[len(sundays)-2]
}

// https://www.gov.uk/when-do-the-clocks-change
func MarchClockSwitchTime(year int) time.Time {
    lastSunday := lastUTCSunday(year, int(time.March)) // month: 3
    return time.Date(
        year, lastSunday.Month(), lastSunday.Day(),
        1, 0, 0, 0, // 1:00 AM
        lastSunday.Location(),
    )
}

// https://www.gov.uk/when-do-the-clocks-change
func OctoberClockSwitchTime(year int) time.Time {
    lastSunday := lastUTCSunday(year, int(time.October)) // month: 10
    return time.Date(
        year, lastSunday.Month(), lastSunday.Day(),
        2, 0, 0, 0, // 2:00 AM
        lastSunday.Location(),
    )
}
```

I've also written some tests using GoConvey that should validate these weird Daylight saving (DST) rules based Sundays, but they work just for 2019, 2020. It would be good to find a way to make this code more general.

```golang
func TestLastSunday(t *testing.T) {
    Convey("Should find the last UTC Sunday of each month\n\n", t, func() {
        for year := 2019; year <= 2020; year++ {
            for month := 1; month <= 12; month++ {
                lastUtcSunday := lastUTCSunday(year, month)

                So(lastUtcSunday.Month(), ShouldEqual, time.Month(month))
                So(lastUtcSunday.Weekday().String(), ShouldEqual, "Sunday")
                So(lastUtcSunday.Year(), ShouldEqual, year)
                So(lastUtcSunday.Day(), ShouldBeGreaterThanOrEqualTo, 28-7)
            }
        }
    })
}

// https://www.gov.uk/when-do-the-clocks-change
func TestClockChange(t *testing.T) {
    Convey("Should find the last UTC Sunday for the March switch\n\n", t, func() {
        switch2019 := MarchClockSwitchTime(2019)
        So(switch2019.Month(), ShouldEqual, time.March)
        So(switch2019.Weekday().String(), ShouldEqual, "Sunday")
        So(switch2019.Day(), ShouldEqual, 31)
        So(switch2019.Location().String(), ShouldEqual, "UTC")
        So(switch2019.Location().String(), ShouldEqual, time.UTC.String())

        switch2020 := MarchClockSwitchTime(2020)
        So(switch2020.Month(), ShouldEqual, time.March)
        So(switch2020.Weekday().String(), ShouldEqual, "Sunday")
        So(switch2020.Day(), ShouldEqual, 29)
        So(switch2020.Location().String(), ShouldEqual, "UTC")
        So(switch2020.Location().String(), ShouldEqual, time.UTC.String())
    })
    Convey("Should find the last UTC Sunday for the October switch\n\n", t, func() {
        switch2019 := OctoberClockSwitchTime(2019)
        So(switch2019.Month(), ShouldEqual, time.October)
        So(switch2019.Weekday().String(), ShouldEqual, "Sunday")
        So(switch2019.Day(), ShouldEqual, 27)
        So(switch2019.Location().String(), ShouldEqual, "UTC")
        So(switch2019.Location().String(), ShouldEqual, time.UTC.String())

        switch2020 := OctoberClockSwitchTime(2020)
        So(switch2020.Month(), ShouldEqual, time.October)
        So(switch2020.Weekday().String(), ShouldEqual, "Sunday")
        So(switch2020.Day(), ShouldEqual, 25)
        So(switch2020.Location().String(), ShouldEqual, "UTC")
        So(switch2020.Location().String(), ShouldEqual, time.UTC.String())
    })
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately all those details are held in unexported fields in the `time` package: https://golang.org/src/time/zoneinfo.go

Answer (score 1):

Go already has full [IANA TZDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) support via [`time.LoadLocation`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#LoadLocation).  Use `Europe/London` for the UK, `Europe/Copenhagen` for CET/CEST in Denmark, etc.  See [the list here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

You should not re-implement time zone logic yourself.  As Tom Scott aptly quips in [The Problem with Time & Timezones](https://youtu.be/-5wpm-gesOY) - *"That way lies madness."*

Comment: The problem I have is not about loading (or switching between) time-zones. It's not even about re-implementing time-zones. It's about struggling to programmatically find the future day when a Daylight Saving Time (DST, the BST part of `Europe/London`, the CEST part of `Europe/Copenhagen`) will activate/deactivate. The Go standard library provides some functionality via the links you and I posted, but it does not seem to be rich enough to assist on DST, so I was wondering if either I was missing something from the docs or I really had to implement that functionality myself (like I did).

Comment: I see.  I guess I misunderstood your question.  You're really after the array of `zoneTrans` objects in the unexported `Location.tx` field.  (See the link Adrian referenced in your question).  Not sure how you would get at it.  Seems like missing functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your situation, it may be practical to call out to [zdump](https://linux.die.net/man/8/zdump) instead, and parse the response.

For example, to list daylight saving transitions for Pacific/Auckland timezone:

```
zdump "Pacific/Auckland" -c 2020,2022 -V
```

Results show NZDT (daylight time) or NZST (standard time), and 'isdst' flag:

```
Pacific/Auckland  Sat Apr  4 13:59:59 2020 UT = Sun Apr  5 02:59:59 2020 NZDT isdst=1 gmtoff=46800
Pacific/Auckland  Sat Apr  4 14:00:00 2020 UT = Sun Apr  5 02:00:00 2020 NZST isdst=0 gmtoff=43200
Pacific/Auckland  Sat Sep 26 13:59:59 2020 UT = Sun Sep 27 01:59:59 2020 NZST isdst=0 gmtoff=43200
Pacific/Auckland  Sat Sep 26 14:00:00 2020 UT = Sun Sep 27 03:00:00 2020 NZDT isdst=1 gmtoff=46800
Pacific/Auckland  Sat Apr  3 13:59:59 2021 UT = Sun Apr  4 02:59:59 2021 NZDT isdst=1 gmtoff=46800
```

Comment: This `zdump` commands seems quite useful (e.g. for `zdump "Europe/London" -c 2020,2021 -V` or `zdump "Europe/Copenhagen" -c 2020,2021 -V`). It seems to be working only on Linux, is there an equivalent version for Windows?